# EditText on the bottom of Relative Layout overlays views under it

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

LinearLayout  with editText on the bottom overlays the content of scrollView, which is filled programmatically. 
How to avoid this please?
I have simplified the XML in vain in my first version of this message.
I have added the full code now

I'd like to keep my editText height expandable.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/backNormal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<include layout="@layout/adview"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="@color/back1"
              android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
            >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textChatSubjectTitle"
                android:text='Subject'
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                />
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textChatActn"
                    android:text='0'
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                    android:paddingRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textWhite"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    />
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textChatUsers"
                    android:text='users'
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageChatImageTitle"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            />
</LinearLayout>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scrollChat"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/backNormal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@+id/linearChat"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
            >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/back1"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonClip"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/clip32"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity= "center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            />


    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editChatMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:maxLength="500"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text=''
            android:layout_gravity= "center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/text1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/edit"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChatSend"
            android:text='>'
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity= "center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/button_normal"
            />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas please?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use RelativeLayout at the top. Make the LinearLayout with editText come below scrollview

Comment: Oops, sorry. I've added not correct code. I've edited the message above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using Relative layout for parent. And then add the rule above.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/llButton"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"

        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:minLines="3"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text='send'
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, there was wrong code in my message. I've corrected. There is RelativeLayout. And the problem is that the bottom layout overlays the scrollView. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes! I've understood now. You've added "layout_above="@+id/llButton". And it works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try the  below code, if it solves your problem.


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1200dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editMessage"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit"
                    android:gravity="top|left"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:minLines="3"
                    android:textColor="@color/text1"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                     />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_normal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="send"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```